# Basic String editing with FileWriter

Tags: java, filewriter

I have 2 Strings that I want to add to a txt File. The first String needs to be in the first Line, the second one in the second line. The "\n" command seems not to work, because in my output file both Strings are in one line.

```
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(measurements);
    String text1 = x.measurementToString(x);
    String text2 = z.measurementToString(z);
    writer.write(text1 + "\n" + text2);
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("Strings added to file!");
```

Comment: working fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the new line character is different in different OSes, you can use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to get newline char for the operating system at runtime.

For Java 7 you can also use `System.lineSeparator()`

Comment: Java translates a `\n` automatically to whatever is appropriate for the platform you're on.

Comment: @SeverityOne Are you sure about that? hat would really suprise me. If I write a character constant I don't expect Java to mess with that.

Comment: @SeverityOne i dont think it does that and that would be counter-intuitive if that happens. Here is Sir JonSkeet saying i think [the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248397/1304575)

Comment: @SeverityOne No it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are on windows and opening the file with a tool that does not recognise `\n` as a line separator, such as notepad?

File I/O is easier with the methods in [the `Files` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html). In your case:

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:/path/to/your/file/filename.ext");
//or
Path p = measurements.toPath();

Files.write(p, Arrays.asList(text1, text2), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This will use the default line separator on your computer and should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use PrintWriter.println() instead.

It must be something like that:

```
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file)) {
    writer.println(text1);
    writer.println(text2);
}
```